# Strange lighting line when rendering in Cycles

Tags: animation, light

This is a frame from a quick rigid body physics animation test in Cycles. For some reason, there's a line separating light from darkness in the background. I can't seem to figure out why.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to BSE, can you add screen shots of your world settings and node editor?

Comment: Are you using an HDR for lighting?

Answer (score 0):

Since the tower is casting a shadow on the darker part of the background I assume that the darker part of the background is your ground plane and the brighter part of your background is your sky from world settings.